# Accessing list items within dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to work out if this is the cleanest way to access the individual temps (ints) for a given location when using a combination of lists and dicts.

```py
Multi_City_Forecast =  [ 
    { 'place': {'city' : "Blacksburg, VA", 'zip code' : 24061} , 'forecast' : [76, 72, 64] } , 
    { 'place': {'city' : "Seattle, WA",    'zip code' : 98101} , 'forecast' : [63, 63, 69] } , 
    { 'place': {'city' : "Miami, FL",      'zip code' : 33101} , 'forecast' : [86, 87, 88] } , 
    { 'place': {'city' : "San Jose, CA",   'zip code' : 95103} , 'forecast' : [79, 82, 83] } , 
    { 'place': {'city' : "New York, NY",   'zip code' : 10036} , 'forecast' : [85, 88, 92] }
]

for forecast in Multi_City_Forecast:
    z = forecast['forecast']
    for a in z:
        print(a)
```

The above code does provide the following (which is what I want) but is it the best way to do it?:

> 76
>
> 72
>
> 64
>
> 63
>
> 63
>
> 69
>
> 86
>
> 87
>
> 88
>
> 79
>
> 82
>
> 83
>
> 85
>
> 88
>
> 92

Any views please?  Thank you.

Comment: *best* in what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reduce it to

```py
for forecast in Multi_City_Forecast:
    for a in forecast['forecast']:
        print(a)
```

But other than that this seems like the most efficient it can be.

Comment: Also refer to @James answer

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print them out one line per city, you can put each on one line using:

```
for forecast in Multi_City_Forecast:
    print(*forecast['forecast'])

# prints
76 72 64
63 63 69
86 87 88
79 82 83
85 88 92
```

Comment: What does the `*` indicate?

Comment: It does tuple unpacking.  In other words it expands each list of temperatures as a set of arguments to the print function

Answer (score 0):

If what you really want is to print every number in each line for one line, the solution given by Jammy Dodger is a good a approach, if you want to be a little fancier, you can go with some list comprehension of the likes of the following for the same result:

```
for forecast in Multi_City_Forecast: 
   [print(a) for a in forecast["forecast"]]
```

Obviously you can go a little deeper with the list comprehension and do something like this:

```
[a for forecast in Multi_City_Forecast for a in forecast["forecast"]]
```

But keep in mind this will throw at you a list:

```
[76, 72, 64, 63, 63, 69, 86, 87, 88, 79, 82, 83, 85, 88, 92]
```

Obviously, you can keep the `print()` statement to open the comprehension:

```
[print(a) for forecast in Multi_City_Forecast for a in forecast["forecast"]]
```

But it will throw the following result, which perhaps is not ideal:

```
76
72
64
63
63
69
86
87
88
79
82
83
85
88
92
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```